# Java Scheduled Executor Service Capabilities

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm designing a server in which I need to be able to schedule thousands of tasks. The task gets executed every 5 seconds. Will the scheduledexecutorservice be able to handle the thousands of tasks with good accuracy? I'm trying to do the timing in just one thread. But the actual tasks will be executed in a thread pool. Thanks

I'm unsure exactly how it works so if anyone could clarify that as well it'd be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

[`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is backed by a thread pool. Roughly speaking you can calculate the number of threads required to run tasks concurrently without delays using the following equation:

> minimal number of threads in the pool is equal to average number of tasks executed per second times average task run time

For example on average you start 2 tasks taking 3 seconds (on average) to finish, you need 6 threads. Of course this assumes fairly uniform distribution of tasks over time.

You can also use [`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) which can theoretically run infinite number of tasks concurrently. Obviously available memory and number of context switches will greatly reduce this number.

If your usage scenario is: run thousands of tasks schedule at exact same point in time every five seconds - neither JVM nor any other platform will handle that. Even if you have *thousands of threads*, you are limited by the number of CPU cores. Accuracy is highly dependent on the nature of your tasks (CPU-intensive? blocking I/O?)

Comment: Do the tasks create a thread in their timing period? Like if i time a task to run in 5 seconds will it open a new thread/use a nee thread instantly or does it not do that until 5 seconds are up?

Comment: @Tukhes: it depends on which thread pool you use. Some pools create a *fixed* number of threads and if all are used your task waits. Other *cache* already created threads so that if new task has to be executed it either uses cached one or pool creates new thread if all are used. Some thread pools also shut down idle threads after some time.

Comment: Ok but lets say i time a task to execute in 5 seconds. When is the thread created? Now or in 5 seconds? @Tomasz Nurkiewicz

Comment: @Tukhes: fully depends on thread pool you choose. You can create all in advance or lazily. If lazily, thread will be created only when needed, i.e. after 5 seconds. But it will survive idle and be reused after another 5 seconds.

Comment: by now i mean when the task is scheduled not necesarily when i start my application @tomasz nurkiewicz

Comment: @Tukhes: sorry, I don't follow. Your `ScheduledExecutorService` knows when to run your task. When the time comes, it asks underlying thread pool for an idle thread. If there is none, it creates new one or waits, depending on pool implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you read the javadocs of scheduler executor service. Is there any particular point that makes you doubt it's Industrial strength. You should use it and measure your performance to check whether it matches your use case.

Also, unless you have strong reason you should not tinker with the implementation of the library class (segregating scheduling and task execution threads on the client side)

However, you should evaluate using a library like quartz if your scheduling criteria are expected to get complicated - beyond the basic use cases provided by the scheduler executor service.

Comment: You should try answering the question when you write an answerr but thanks anyways